# Validation of route parameters in lumen without facades

Tags: php, validation, laravel, lumen

Hope you guys can help me, searched long and hard but cannot find my answer.

I am building an API in Lumen, I have a GET route that points to a controller, defined as:

```
public function mymethod(Request $request, $param1, $param2, $param3)
```

With POST/PUT routes, I use the included validator as such:

```
$validator = app('validator')->make($request->all(), $rules, $messages, $customAttributes );
```

In the GET route outlined above, dd( $request->all() ) returns an empty array (as expected I guess), is there any way to get an array of all the route parameters that have been passed to the method so that I can validate them without writing ugly and specific validation rules?

I could do it manually like:

```
$parameters = [ 'param1' => $param1, 'param2' => $param2, ... ]
```

but I was wondering if there was a Laravel way, looks like the Input::all() method might do what I need, but I would prefer to avoid using facades.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Enabled facades and tested Input::all(). It does not return route parameters passed to controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Input` facade is just a facade to your `$request` variable, so `Input::all()` and `$request->all()` are basically the same thing.

The thing to keep in mind, though, is that you're looking for route parameters, not query string parameters. The request only knows about query string parameters, so you really need to drill down to the route object to get the route parameters.

After looking through the Lumen code, I believe you'll want something like this. The code can be chained together, I just broke it into separate lines to be able to comment each step.

```
// get the Illuminate\Http\Request object for the current request
$request = app('request');

// get the route information associated with the current request
$route = $request->route();

// route parameters are the 3rd item in the route info array
$params = $route[2];

// chained code (just for completeness)
$params = app('request')->route()[2];

// validate
$validator = app('validator')->make($params, $rules, $messages, $customAttributes);
```